# Delete and recreate the registry for an azure machine learning workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Our azure machine learning workspace container registry has grown extremely large (4Tb) and has many obsolete entries. I would like to delete the registry and simply create a new one. We do not need any entries from the old one.

If I delete the current registry, create a new one, how do I attach it to the workspace?  I dont want to create a new workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching a registry to an existing workspace can be done with this command (replace placeholders with your own values):

```
az ml workspace update -n [ML workspace name] -g [Resource group name] --container-registry [ACR ID] -u
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?